# How would I go about implementing license keys in my Discord.js bot?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I came on StackOverflow today to ask this question. How would I go about implementing a serial key for my Discord bot? I want to make it so if you haven't entered your serial key, then none of the commands will work. I don't want the serial keys to be re-used, or used in other guilds. I'm kinda confused right now, can someone help me out and point out what I should do?

Answer (score 0):

if you have a mysql database you can do something along the lines of this:

```js
const mysql = require("mysql")

/* ------------------------------------------------- *
 *             On Recieved Message                   *
 * ------------------------------------------------- */
client.on('message', async message => {
    // ...

    var active = false;

    // if server has active key already
    Database.query(`select * from table where server = '${client.guilds.get(message.guild.id).id}'`, (err, rows) => {
        if (err) return console.log(err)
        if (!rows || rows.length <= 0) {
            return Database.query(`Insert into table (id, active) values (${client.guilds.get(message.guild.id).id}, false)`)
        }

        active = rows[0].active
    })

    // activate key
    if (message.content.startsWith('!activate')) {

        // if key exists in table: key
        Database.query(`select * from keys where key = '${message.content.split(" ")[1]}'`, (err, rows) => {
            if (err) return console.log(err)
            if (!rows || rows.lenght <= 0) {
                return message.channel.send('Invalid code')
            } else {
                let key = rows[0].key
                    // if key exists remove and update server table
                Database.query(`update server set active = 'true' where id = '${client.guilds.get(message.guild.id).id}'`, (err, rows) => {
                    if (err) return console.log(err)
                    active = true;

                    Database.query(`Delete from keys where key = '${key}'`)

                })
            }
        })
    }

    // if server has active key let them continue else return them
    if (!active == 'true') return;
    // Command handler;

});
```

as for generating the key, ill leave that up to you. (have a look at uuid generators if you have no clue.)

---

Comment: Thank you so much!!